# Cygwin + Gdb Simple_Program

Tags: gdb, g++, cygwin

I wrote this simple program in cygwin:

```
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    int a;
    float b;
    std::cout << "Podaj liczbe calkowita: ";
    std::cin >> a;
    std::cout << "Podaj liczbe rzeczywista: ";
    std::cin >> b;
    std::cout << "Liczba a = " << a << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Liczba b = " << b << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

When I try to debug it with `gdb`, (compiling with `-g` option), and I get this as my output:

```
g++ -o -g test test.cpp
test: In function `mainCRTStartup':
/usr/src/debug/cygwin-2.4.1-1/winsup/cygwin/crt0.c:23: multiple definition of `mainCRTStartup'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.9.3/../../../../lib/crt0.o:/usr/src/debug/cygwin-2.4.1-1/winsup/cygwin/crt0.c:23: first defined here
test: In function `mainCRTStartup':
/usr/src/debug/cygwin-2.4.1-1/winsup/cygwin/crt0.c:23: multiple definition of `WinMainCRTStartup'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.9.3/../../../../lib/crt0.o:/usr/src/debug/cygwin-2.4.1-1/winsup/cygwin/crt0.c:23: first defined here
test:cygming-crtbegin.c:(.text+0x60): multiple definition of `__gcc_register_frame'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.9.3/crtbegin.o:cygming-crtbegin.c:(.text+0x10): first defined here
test:cygming-crtbegin.c:(.text+0xd0): multiple definition of `__gcc_deregister_frame'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.9.3/crtbegin.o:cygming-crtbegin.c:(.text+0x80): first defined here
test:crt0.c:(.data+0x0): multiple definition of `__dso_handle'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.9.3/crtbegin.o:cygming-crtbegin.c:(.data+0x0): first defined here
test:crt0.c:(.text+0x50): multiple definition of `.weak._Jv_RegisterClasses.__dso_handle'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.9.3/crtbegin.o:cygming-crtbegin.c:(.text+0x0): first defined here
test:crt0.c:(.idata+0x1d0): multiple definition of `__imp__ZSt3cin'
test:crt0.c:(.idata+0x1d0): first defined here
test:crt0.c:(.idata+0x1d8): multiple definition of `__imp__ZSt4cout'
test:crt0.c:(.idata+0x1d8): first defined here
/tmp/ccG5Ono8.o:test.cpp:(.text+0x0): multiple definition of `main'
test:test.cpp:(.text+0xe0): first defined here
/tmp/ccG5Ono8.o:test.cpp:(.rdata$.refptr._ZSt4cout[.refptr._ZSt4cout]+0x0): multiple definition of `.refptr._ZSt4cout'
test:test.cpp:(.rdata+0xb0): first defined here
/tmp/ccG5Ono8.o:test.cpp:(.rdata$.refptr._ZSt3cin[.refptr._ZSt3cin]+0x0): multiple definition of `.refptr._ZSt3cin'
test:cygming-crtbegin.c:(.rdata+0xa0): first defined here
/tmp/ccG5Ono8.o:test.cpp:(.rdata$.refptr._ZSt4endlIcSt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIT_T0_ES6_[.refptr._ZSt4endlIcSt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIT_T0_ES6_]+0x0): multiple definition of `.refptr._ZSt4endlIcSt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIT_T0_ES6_'
test:test.cpp:(.rdata+0xc0): first defined here
/tmp/ccG5Ono8.o:test.cpp:(.rdata$.refptr.__dso_handle[.refptr.__dso_handle]+0x0): multiple definition of `.refptr.__dso_handle'
test:test.cpp:(.rdata+0xd0): first defined here
/tmp/ccG5Ono8.o:test.cpp:(.rdata$.refptr._ZNSt8ios_base4InitD1Ev[.refptr._ZNSt8ios_base4InitD1Ev]+0x0): multiple definition of `.refptr._ZNSt8ios_base4InitD1Ev'
test:cygming-crtbegin.c:(.rdata+0x90): first defined here
/tmp/ccG5Ono8.o:test.cpp:(.rdata$.refptr._ZSt3cin[.refptr._ZSt3cin]+0x0): multiple definition of `__fu0__ZSt3cin'
test:cygming-crtbegin.c:(.rdata+0xa0): first defined here
/tmp/ccG5Ono8.o:test.cpp:(.rdata$.refptr._ZSt4cout[.refptr._ZSt4cout]+0x0): multiple definition of `__fu1__ZSt4cout'
test:test.cpp:(.rdata+0xb0): first defined here
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.9.3/crtbegin.o:cygming-crtbegin.c:(.text+0x35): undefined reference to `_Jv_RegisterClasses'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.9.3/crtbegin.o:cygming-crtbegin.c:(.text+0x35): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol `_Jv_RegisterClasses'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
./test.exe
```

Any ideas on why I am getting this?

Comment: Try `g++ -g -o test test.cpp` .  `g++ -o -g test test.cpp` tells the compiler to compile `test.cpp`, link it with the existing `test` executable (yielding multiple definitions), and output to a file named `-g`.

Comment: Ok thanks Mark That solve problem